# Which is the shortcut to reveal in project view current file?

Tags: goland

I want to reveal current file in project view as same as VSCode does when you use alt+shift+f command (or similar)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Select in...` feature. Press *Alt + F1 on Windows/Linux* or *⌥ + F1 on macOS*. [Here's a demo](https://www.jetbrains.com/go/guide/tips/select-in/) of this feature.

Comment: I've import visual studio keymap. This shortcut is not working for me right now.

Comment: You can customize your shortcut via `Settings/Preferences | Keymap`. Navigate to `Main Menu | Navigate | Select In...` or search for `Select in...`.

Answer (score 6):

I had to go to cog icon in left side project view window
[image: left project view float window]

Then click on it and select `Always Select Opened File` option so then everytime I select a file from code editor top bar where opened files are listed file is revealed in project view window